# DBGrid not show records

Tags: delphi, dbexpress, dbgrid

Im try populate grid in Delphi, with values from database. For now, i have a TSQLConnection, TSQLQuery, TDataSource and TDBGrid.

The components are associated as follows:

1) myTDBGrid DataSource: myTDataSOurce
2) myTDataSource DataSet: myTSQLQuery
3) myTSQLQuery Connection: myTSQLConnection

When compile and run a error message broke the application:

> Operation not allowed on a unidirectional dataset

Any ideas ?.

Comment: @KenWhite, this is expected behaviour for dbExpress.

Comment: @Uwe: Right. I missed that it was dbExpress. Thanks for the catch. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all. Im using the next article: [Building aVCL Forms dvExpress](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Building_a_VCL_Forms_dbExpress_Database_Application) and works.

Answer (score 5):

This is standard behaviour for dbExpress: all TSQLDataSets are unidirectional and a TDBGrid cannot handle those.

The solution is to use a TClientDataSet connected to a TDataSetProvider, which itself connects to TSQLQuery.

May I suggest reading the [dbExpress tutorial](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Tutorial%3a_Using_dbExpress_to_View_and_Update_Databases_in_an_Application)?